# Button OnClick from Fragment to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclick

I have 3 Fragments inside my `MainActivity` and in one of my Fragments I have 3 `ImageView` and each of image view performs same action based on which `ImageView` was selected, now What I want to achieve is that instead of using `OnClickListener` for each of Views separately, call same method with switch-case or if-else inside. But the problem is those `ImageViews` inside fragment cannot call Functions implemented inside MainActivity. for instance. here's the code to understand what I want to say:

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
public void imageClicked(View v){
    if(v.getID() == findViewById(R.id.id_of_imageView_1).getID()){
        myTextView.setText("ImageView 1 is Clicked")
    }
    
    else if(v.getID() == findViewById(R.id.id_of_imageView_2).getID()){
        myTextView.setText("ImageView 2 is Clicked")
    }

    else if(v.getID() == findViewById(R.id.id_of_imageView_3).getID()){
        myTextView.setText("ImageView 3 is Clicked")
    }
}
```

**XML (fragment_images.xml) WHERE IMAGES EXIST**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/id_of_imageView_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/laptop" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/id_of_imageView_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/memory" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/id_of_imageView_3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/screen" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**XML (activity_main.xml) HERE I Link my Fragment and TextView**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

     //CHANGE THIS TEXT VIEW WHEN IMAGE IS CLICKED
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Select Product"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
            android:name="com.salmanibrahim.calssifiedelectronics.ListFrag"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
            android:name="com.salmanibrahim.calssifiedelectronics.DetailFrag"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />

        //THIS IS THE FRAGMENT
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_images"
            android:name="com.salmanibrahim.calssifiedelectronics.AddProduct"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_images" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

How do I call `imageClicked()` defined inside `MainActivity` using `onClick` on `ImageView`

Comment: yes exactly, I want to use it as ```android:onClick="imageClicked"``` but since the ```ImageView``` is inside a fragment and not directly inside activity_main.xml, I can't call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you trying to do but `android:onClick` parameter only links for the context declared in `tools:context` field on the parent tag of your layout file.

So it is not possible to reference your `imageClicked()` function found in your MainActivity from your fragment's `ImageView` because they are in different context. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolscontext) for more info.

Comment: So the thing is that in order to reference ```myFunction()```, the ```targetingView``` must be direct child of context otherwise it isn't possible even if its direct parent i.e. ```myFragment``` is part of the target context. This is what I understand from user guide and your answer, is that so?

Comment: Yes even if the fragment is part of the activity and similar context the layout's xml field tag is for the one that inflated the layout.

Answer (score 2):

In your fragment you can call `imageClicked()` in the `MainActivity` by using `requireActivity()` or `getActivity()` and do the necessary cast

In fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(...) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
    MainActivity mActivity = (MainActivity) requireActivity();

    imageView1 = view.findViewById(...);
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mActivity.imageClicked(imageView1);
        }
    });

    
...}
```

repeat the same for imageView2, 3

Also the condition in `imageClicked()` seems not right as you `findViewById` which will point to your MainActivity layout, not the fragment.

So you need to change this

```
if (v.getID() == findViewById(R.id.id_of_imageView_1).getID())
```

To

```
if (v.getID() == R.id.id_of_imageView_1)
```

And do the same for other images.

Comment: @SalmanMalik thanks for that .. but notice you used `findViewById` in activity .. and you need to get the images from the activity layout while they exist in fragment .. this is because using `findViewById ` in activity will point to the activity layout not the fragment layout.. then it won't find the image in the activity layout .. in this case it can raise `NullPointerException`.. just give it a try .. thanks to accept the answer if it targets your issue

Comment: Yeah Resources are global , but `findViewById` points to a certain layout that has certain resource Ids .. if you call it in activity, then it points only to the activity layout including the Ids in it.. but in your case images exist in fragment layout and to access them you need to call `getView().findViewById` within the fragment itself,, Just please let us discuss when attempt that in your code

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in wrong way.
You can do this instead.

```
imageView_1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then implement activity from `View.onClickListener`

then get view by id on the method that's been implemented.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.id_of_imageView_1:
            // do your things here
            break;
        }
}
```